# How to return user input when multiple functions are used?

Tags: javascript, html

Junior developer here trying to understand why my code is not working as intended. There are two text fields in my code (Tag 1 and Tag 2), my intention is to concatenate the values of those fields together. I use a function called validateForm to validate that a value is present in both fields; if a value is not present in either field, an alert box displays.

If a value is present in both, I want the validateForm function to call the assembleTags function to concatenate the values the user inputs to one another. Separately, there is also a "reset" button that is intended to reset the generator when clicked. What might I be doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">
<form id="concatenation" method="post">
Tag 1<br>
<input type="text" name="tag_1" id="tag1" size="75">
<br>
<br>
Tag 2
<br>
<input type="text" name="tag_2" id="tag2" size="75">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="get_tags" id="gettags" value ="Get Tags" onclick="assembleTags()" style="cursor:pointer">
<input type="button" name="reset_generator" id="resetgenerator" value="Reset Generator" onclick="myServerReset()" style="cursor:pointer">
<br>
<br>
<h3 id="result"></h3>
</form>
</p>
<script>
function validateForm()
    var a = document.forms['concatenation']['tag1'].value;
    var b = document.forms['concatenation']['tag2'].value;
    if (a == "" && b == "") {
        alert("Please include Tag 1 and Tag 2"); 
        return false;
    } 
    else if (a == "" && b != "") {
        alert("Please include Tag 1")
        return false;
    }
    else if (a != "" && b == "") {
        alert("Please include Tag 2")
        return false;
    else
        assembleTags() {
    }
function assembleTags() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('tag1').value + document.getElementById('tag2').value
}
}
function myServerReset() {
document.getElementById('concatenation').reset();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what problem are you facing? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: `<input type="submit"...` submits the form data to the server. To prevent this (default) behavior `onclick` handler must `return false;`. Simply change `onclick="validateForm()` for `onclick="return validateForm();`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I changedthe onclick event to "return validateForm()"; and it is still sending a request to the server.

Comment: @Yousaf - There are two issues. The button that activates the assembling of the user inputs is returning an error, and the button that activates the resetting of the form generator is not working, either. Whenever I click the button that activates the function that assembles the values together, Google throws back a response of "The requested URL was not found on this server".

Comment: ^ Please merge this update into the question. You may need to be more specific than "not working" - this is rather vague at present.

Comment: @halfer - This has been resolved.

Comment: Lovely. Ideally, to benefit future readers, please edit the question to make the improvements requested above. That will allow us to potentially reopen the question, and then you can add an answer, if that might be helpful to future readers.

Comment: To All - Please see Fred's answer. I had a few of the opening and closing braces that were either in the incorrect places or missing. This has now been resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is a pasting error but are the opening and closing braces correct?

For example:

- Missing opening brace after `function validateForm()`
- Misplaced opening brace after the `else`

  `else
      assembleTags() {
  }`
- Additional closing brace after `function assembleTags()`

Comment: Thank you, Fred! I made the fix to the braces and that fixed it.